# Warning: Creating default object from empty value in

Tags: php

I have a script which tests the connection speed. When I moved it to another server I got the following warning:

```
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /home/speed/public_html/common.php on line 26
```

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
## Read through the config file and assign items to the global $config variable
function ReadConfig($config_file) {
    global $config;
    $lines = file($config_file);
    foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
        $line = rtrim(preg_replace("/#.*/","",$line));
        if(preg_match("/\[.*\]/", $line, $parts)) {
            $section = $parts[0];
            $section = preg_replace("/[\[\]]/","",$section);
        } elseif (preg_match("/=/",$line)) {
            list($var,$value) = split('=',$line);
            $var = preg_replace('/ $/','',$var);
            $value = preg_replace('/^ +/','',$value);

            $config->{$section}->{$var} = $value; # here
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently running PHP 5.5, the other server runs a newer version of PHP.

Comment: That's not an **error**, it's a *warning*.  It's just telling you that `$config->{$section}` didn't exist, so it created it for you when you did `$config->{$section}->{$var}`.  You should make sure properties exist before trying to add children to them.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix line 26 with this check:

```
if (!isset($config->{$section}))
    $config->{$section} = new Stdclass;
```

and it should work without generating warning

Comment: thanks sjon, i did what u said now insted of multi errors lines its one line, but still same error

Comment: You show us 1 error; I fix that, now you tell us there are more errors? How about posting those too?

Answer (score 1):

@Sjon provides the answer to get rid of the warning, I will just explain why you see the warning now.
Since you moved your code to another server, there is most probably another php ini file and thus, different settings. On your "old" server, you had the `errors` and `warnings` most likely switched off so you did not see them, on the "new" server they are switched on by default.

Instead of displaying errors you can log them so you do not see them while browsing:

```
display_errors(false); 
// you definitely wanna log any occurring
log_errors(true);
```

Comment: hey Bas, i think putting errors in file will generate huge file over time, is there correction to this code or any way to modify php setting to make it right?

Comment: It will not become soo big, and each directory gets his own file. There are many configuration options available. Check the php.ini to get an overview of all possibilities.